# Kafka consumer need to know all the messages received from the topic

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

We need to sort the consumed records in spark streaming of kafka consumer part. Is it possible to know all the published records are consumed in kafka consumer ?

Comment: You want to know if it's possible to see all the offsets consumed from a Kafka topic?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `KafkaConsumer#endOffsets(...)` to get the offsets of the *current* end-of-log per partition. Of course, keep in mind that the end-of-log moves as long as new data is written by a consumer. Thus, for getting "end offsets" you must be sure that there is no running producer...

Comment: Thanks Matthias, Kindly note this is streaming. So producer is running continuously.

Comment: If producer are running continuously, I do not understand your question in the first place... How would you define "know all the published records are consumed" if you permanently add new messages to the log?